# IDENTIFY CIRCUIT IN FXO

Tags: embedded

[image]

This circuit is used in FXO.clarify what is the purpose of this circuit in fxo gateway.refer some link to know more about this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple supply filter for a microprocessor or something.

Comment: thank you for ur answer.i know this circuit is filter& used analog power supply & it is combined with digital power supply.I want to know inner process involved to convert analog P.S to digital P.S

Comment: I think the inductor blocks any AC signal and the capacitors shortciruit the higher frequencys.

Comment: Thanks how to connect SPI interface & PCM interface control signals to embedded board.